# BerryBoot will not connect to any wifi network

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi, berryboot

Trying to get berryboot on my Pi 3B to connect to my WiFi has been a PITA.

When connecting it says "connecting" for a few seconds and then errors with `Error connecting or obtaining IP-address. Check settings.` I've tried connecting to different WiFi networks and know it is not the router causing this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Start to examin the log files in the folder `/var/log` or run the command `dmesg` to see whats fails.

Comment: Berryboot is a boot manager and has normally nothing to do with WiFi. Why do you think it is the source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also. I'm not sure but I think it is a DNS issue.
I tried switching off and on the router and it connected fine after that